# I wanted to create an array whose members are part of other array .I am not being able to find out the error

Tags: c, arrays

I tried to create an array whose members are from a strurcture . I tried the following way but it seems there is not the correct way to do! Please suggest me a better way to do ! at least the right way

```
int vertex [8][3]={{P1.x[0],P1.y[0],P1.z[0]},
                            {P1.x[1],P1.y[1],P1.z[1]},
                            {P1.x[2],P1.y[2],P1.z[2]},
                            {P1.x[3],P1.y[3],P1.z[3]},
                            {P1.x[4],P1.y[4],P1.z[4]},
                            {P1.x[5],P1.y[5],P1.z[5]},
                            {P1.x[6],P1.y[6],P1.z[6]},
                            {P1.x[7],P1.y[7],P1.z[7]}};
```

Comment: I believe C array initializers have to be compile-time constants. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c among others. I'm afraid you're going to have to do this programmatically... which, for the example you've shown, is certainly a simple enough loop.

Comment: Works for `gcc` (GCC 4.8.2). Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -c`. (GCC 4.8.2)

Here is my test source:

```
typedef struct {
    int *x, *y, *z;
} P;

void foo(void) {
    P P1;

    int vertex [8][3]={
        {P1.x[0],P1.y[0],P1.z[0]},
        {P1.x[1],P1.y[1],P1.z[1]},
        {P1.x[2],P1.y[2],P1.z[2]},
        {P1.x[3],P1.y[3],P1.z[3]},
        {P1.x[4],P1.y[4],P1.z[4]},
        {P1.x[5],P1.y[5],P1.z[5]},
        {P1.x[6],P1.y[6],P1.z[6]},
        {P1.x[7],P1.y[7],P1.z[7]}
    };

    (void) vertex[0][0];
}
```

Comment: @novice1618 If you like it, you may accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be using `P1[1].x` instead of `P1.x[1]` as per P1 struct definition

And although it will work but the efficient way will be to use a for loop.

```
vertex[8][3]={0}; //Initialized to all 0s
for (i=0;i<8;i++)
{
   vertex[i][0]= P1[i].x;
   vertex[i][1]= P1[i].y;
   vertex[i][2]= P1[i].z;
}
```

Comment: Works for GCC 4.8.2. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: broken foot I tried the way you have suggested but it still gives error "structure required on the left side of a . " something like this

Comment: @novice1618 What is the definition of your `P1`?

Comment: p1 is defined as structure

Comment: OP: Yes, how is P1 defined?
@leeduhem: Indeed, it works. Thanks for the enlightenment!
I'll edit my answer. But it is not an efficient way to do it, the fastest way to update the values is to put them in a loop.

Comment: struct PolygonVertex
    {
          int x,y,z;
    };
PolygonVertex P1[7];

Comment: @novice1618 That is your problem, the type of `P1` is wrong. Please refer to my answer. And you should update your question and include the definition of `P1` in it.

Comment: @novice1618, check my ans, you should be using `P1[1].x` instead of `P1.x[1]` as per P1 struct definition

Comment: @brokenfoot You are right, this is not an efficient way to initialize `P1`.

Comment: @novice1618: Also, kindly add the definition of P1 in the question as well, it will present more clarity to the question.